# A word spoken rarely or never

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I would like to know an unambiguous term used to designate words that are spoken vanishingly rarely, if at all.

> Words that are never spoken, `_________`, illustrate the fundamental difference between spoken and written languages.

Such words as would be designated by the term might be scientific coinages, difficult to pronounce, prosodically awkward; whatever the reason, although the word can be pronounced, it is not; such a word is only encountered in written form.

When I attempted to recall the term, all I could come up with was

> **dictionary word**, *n.*
>   (a) a word which may be found in a dictionary, a valid word;  (b) a word which has been listed in a dictionary but which is rarely or never used, an obscure or recondite word.

["dictionary, n. and adj.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52325?rskey=jj89IT&result=1&isAdvanced=true (accessed January 07, 2016).]

As can be seen, 'dictionary word', while it might be stretched to fit my use, is unsuitable in that (a) the first meaning given does not correspond to the meaning I intend, and (b) the second meaning given is inaccurate. The meaning in (b) is inaccurate and misleading because, for example, many scientific coinages are spoken rarely or never, but they will also never appear in a dictionary.

The term 'recondite word' might also be used, but it is inexact. 'Obscure word' suffers likewise.

Having failed to recall or discover the term, I am of course prepared to accept it does not exist; however, I seem to remember such a term being bandied about in some graduate English, Classics or Linguistics course in the early 1980s.

Comment: I've heard the term *mute word* for a word that has no spoken form at all, but I can't prove this with references. Ironically, your topic also could use examples of words that are only spoken,,,,,, if only they could be written down.

Comment: 'When I attempted to recall the term' indicates that you once knew that term, and hence that it exists. Is that true?

Comment: It would probably be useful for the OP to differentiate between "archaic" and "obsolete" words: http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/Obsolete-Word.htm

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I have to confess my memory is a more slippery item than you propose. It makes things up. In this case, I *thought*, I've been carrying around with me for many years the *notion* that I at one time knew such a word but, being unable to recall it and instead recalling 'dictionary word' cast that *notion* in doubt. As for the memory, it is quite detailed: I have a visual image of the professor writing the word in question on the blackboard underneath *dictionary word* when discussing the nuances of the concept. He pointed at the word with chalk in his left hand.

Comment: It's the use of 'recall' (which [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recall) defines as 'Bring (a fact, event, or situation) back into one’s mind; remember:' well before 'I seem to remember such a term being bandied about in some graduate English ... course' that makes garden path sentences look uncomplicated. // The underlying assumption necessary for a sound answer here is that the term 'word' itself is unambiguously defined. Previous threads have not shown this to be the truth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider using [**archaic words**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/archaic-words) which are:

> These words are **no longer in everyday use** or have lost a particular
>   meaning in current usage but are sometimes used to impart an
>   old-fashioned flavour to historical novels, for example, or in
>   standard conversation or writing just for a humorous effect. Some,
>   such as *hotchpotch*, reveal the origin of their current meaning, while
>   others reveal the origin of a different modern word, as with gentle,
>   the sense of which is preserved in gentleman. Some, such as learn and
>   let, now mean the opposite of their former use.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Archaic words might suffer the same problem as other suggestions you included in  the question, but "rarely (never) spoken word" could be the right phrase.

Comment: Yes, 'archaic' or the noun 'archaism' would require my explaining away even more dissonance than 'dictionary word' or 'recondite word', but +1 because I might have to accept 'rarely or never spoken word'.

Comment: I guess "rarely spoken word" is the best I can get. Thanks for the answer--it proved to be the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

**archaism** [ahr-kee-iz-uh m, -key-] noun 1. something archaic, as a word or expression.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/archaism?s=t

In language, an **archaism** is the use of a form of speech or writing that is no longer current or that is current only within a few special contexts. Their deliberate use can be subdivided into ***literary*** **archaisms**, which seeks to evoke the style of older speech and writing; and ***lexical archaisms***, the use of words no longer in common use.

Comment: Surely literary archaisms are no longer in common use. '...and of lexical archaisms, which doesn't.'?